# How to add dynamic title to extend page in django?

Tags: python, django, rest

I need to change the title of base.html based on rendered page in the

> {% block content %}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add first the "Block Title" on base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My app - {% block title %}{% block title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% block title %}
</body>
</html>
```

and then you can change it when you call it

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}My new title{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<p>My new content</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Nice, short and sweet!